# Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS hangs one or more times a day

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Laptop Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G3 ACL with AMD® Ryzen 5 5500u 16GB RAM 4GB swap. Suddenly it can freeze during work. The mouse cursor moves, but the picture on the screen does not change. The combination Atl+Tab does not work, the keyboard does not work. The last thing that catches my attention in the logs before it hangs:

```
May 18 15:56:30 maxim-lap gnome-shell[2757]: The offending signal was app-state-changed on ShellAppSystem 0x559fc4033fa0.
May 18 15:56:30 maxim-lap gnome-shell[2757]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
```

This two messages repeats many times.

Comment: UPD - i have Ubuntu PRO (maybe it can help?)